# Can't convert all dates to timestamp in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert all the dates into timestamp from a url in json but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, it gives me the following error:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

from dateutil.parser import isoparse
import requests

separator = '\n'
url = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/cosmetics/br/search/all?language=es&name=palito%20de%20pescado%20de%20gominola&searchLanguage=es")

historialSKIN= url.json()



for i in historialSKIN["data"]:
    fecha = isoparse(*i['shopHistory'], sep=separator).timestamp()
    print(fecha)
```

I want to get all dates in timestamp " 1652777302"

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that `isoparse()` takes any `kwarg` named `sep`, considering [the documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse) makes zero mention of such a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As esqew said, `isoparse` doesn't take a `sep` argument. You should loop over the dates and parse them individually, like so:

```py
for i in historialSKIN["data"]:
    for datestr in i['shopHistory']:
        fecha = isoparse(datestr).timestamp()
        print(fecha)
```

Comment: How to replace the .0? i.imgur.com/XTlwYos.png

Comment: @juancarlos5487 if you want it as a string, use `isoparse(datestr).strftime('%s')`, or if you need it as a number, convert it to an int: `int(isoparse(datestr).timestamp())`